# In the Atom, why is this inscription gray and not white and is not activated? (border-stile:)

Tags: css

In the Atom, why is this inscription gray and not white and is not activated? (border-style:)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7b9Z.jpg)How to activate the "border style" in Atom, please help?

Not listed here, how to set border style in Atom, what plugin is needed for this, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Because you missed `;` on the previous line. And you have a typo. Should be `border-style` not `border-stile`.

Comment: Here I am a blind fool, I missed one day for it. Thank you, my glad brother, live long